# Rendering elements in Jade on one line?

Tags: pug

I'm still getting the hang of Jade. The following markup works, however it results in the elements rendering on two seperate lines. I would like the link and the `p.some_classname` text to render on the same line, but not turn `p.some_classname` into a hyperlink.

```
for elem in elems
  a(href="/foo/#{var1}/bar/#{var2}").baz.i.icon-cog
  p.some_classname= elem.id_1 + ' ' + elem.id_2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "on the same line"? The same line in your html or do they render on separate lines in the visible output in the browser

Comment: The visible output in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly, you want the link and the text on the same line with one line per elem.  If so you just need to have the paragraph wrap the text and use a span:

```
for elem in elems
   p.some_classname 
       a(href="/foo/#{var1}/bar/#{var2}").baz.i.icon-cog
       span= elem.id_1 + ' ' + elem.id_2
```

This will generate (for each elem):

```
<p class="some_classname"><a href="/foo..." class="baz i icon-cog"><span>{val for id_1} {val for id_2}</span></p>
```

Or, you could simplify further and skip the span altogether:

```
for elem in elems
   p.some_classname 
       a(href="/foo/#{var1}/bar/#{var2}").baz.i.icon-cog
       | #{elem.id_1} #{elem.id_2}
```

Just tested both using node and either works depending on what you want for final markup. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to selectively remove a newline character between any pair of lines. However, if jade is run without the `--pretty` or `-P` options, the entire output will be collapsed into a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Plus of Matt's answer, you may use **IDs** and **CSS Classes** separetely like that:

```
p 
     | #[ObjectId1.class1 SomeText ]
     | #[ObjectId2.class2 #{jsonObject.attribute}]
```